# VBA importing CSV file to OjbExcel

Tags: vba, csv, scripting

I've been trying to generate an excel by feeding it a .Csv file in VBA. 
We are using a inhouse business program that uses vba so I have to reference to objExcel.

This:

```
Function load_csv()
Dim objExcel
Dim objWorkbook
Dim baseSheet
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.workbooks.Add()
Set baseSheet = objWorkbook.worksheets(1)


With objExcel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;FILENAME.csv", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "CAPTURE"
    .fieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End With
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs

Set objExcel = Nothing
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set baseSheet = Nothing
End Function
```

Gives me an application defined or object defined error.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: ThisWorkbook is used to refer to the workbook containing the currently-running code .  That's not applicable in this case so you should use ActiveWorkbook (as you have later in your posted code).  Also unless you've included a reference to  the Excel object library you can't reference Excels built-in constants without defining a value for them in your code.  For example you code has no idea what the value of xlDelimited is, since that's defined in the Excel library.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I've changed the code to 'activeworkbook', now receiving subscript out of range error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be closer. You will still need to define all Excel constants such as `xlInsertDeleteCells` though.  You can find their values in the VB editor Object Browser (press F2) in Excel.  You should also provide the full path to the CSV file.

```
Function load_csv()

Const xlInsertDeleteCells = 1
Const xlDelimited = 1
Const xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote = 1

Dim objExcel As Object
Dim objWorkbook As Object
Dim baseSheet As Object
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.workbooks.Add()
Set baseSheet = objWorkbook.worksheets(1)


With baseSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;FILENAME.csv", _
                              Destination:=baseSheet.Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "CAPTURE"
    .fieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End With

objWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Temp.xlsx" '<<<< needs a path
objWorkbook.Close False

Set objExcel = Nothing


End Function
```